# Does clojure have a fully inclusive range function?

Tags: clojure

Clojure's [range](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/range) function is inclusive from the `start` and exclusive in the `end` (if provided). Is there a function somewhere in the core library that will provide a fully inclusive (start & end) range?

I find code that has to adjust the end value in certain scenarios - such as a range going downwards rather than upwards (say in a list comprehension) much less readable. E.g.:

```
(range n -1 -1)
```

Am I just missing it in the docs or is there a cleaner way to do this?

I have some fondness for the [guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/RangesExplained) Range API, so I was looking for something of similar flexibility.

Comment: Why do you write it `(range n (- 1) (- 1))` instead of `(range n -1 -1)`?

Comment: hmm good point! i'll update the question.

Answer (score 5):

There is no standard `inclusive-range` function - following [Kevin Ingle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33005344/1562315)'s terminology .

You can build one on top of `range`:

```
(defn inclusive-range
  ([] (range))
  ([end] (range (inc end)))
  ([start end] (range start (inc end)))
  ([start end step] (range start (+ end step) step)))
```

But you run into trouble with ragged ends. For example,

```
(inclusive-range 10 11.5)
;(10 11 12)
```

Not what you want, I think.

Comment: If you like brevity this becomes sort of a pun when shortened to `inc-range`

Comment: It's not obvious what the correct behavior should be be when a final step could overshoot `end`.    `(10 11 12)` doesn't seem intrinsically wrong.  @JohnCollins' `irange` produces `(10 11)`, which also doesn't seem intrinsically wrong.  A more significant problem with `inclusive-range` is due to float slop: `(inclusive-range 0 0.8 0.1) ;=> (0 0.1 0.2 0.30000000000000004 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.7999999999999999 0.8999999999999999)`.  `irange` gets the right result here: `(0 0.1 0.2 0.30000000000000004 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.7999999999999999)`.

Comment: @Mars I've come to prefer JohnCollins version https://stackoverflow.com/a/68476365/1562315. If you replace hsis `<=` with `<`, you get the standard `range`.

Comment: @JohnCollins' version is the one I've adopted.  It's worthwhile to exhibit multiple solutions, though, so even if you prefer another one, I appreciate yours as well.  It's simpler and more elegant in some ways.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there's no core function, but you can just define your own for your use:

```
(defn inclusive-range [start end] (range start (inc end)))
```

or maybe more general -- define a function that just adds the end:

```
(defn inclusive-range [start end step] (flatten (list (range start end step) end)))
```

As pointed out in the comments, the above solutions may not be ideal.  You mentioned that you are used to guava's Range, so you could also just import that and use it:

```
(import 'com.google.common.collect.Range)
(-> (Range/closed 1 10)
    (.contains 10))  ; returns true
```

Comment: in my case the range is decreasing so it would need to be more general than this

Comment: The second example is not only not idiomatic (flatten is almost never something you want to use in Clojure) but also broken in a number of ways. e.g. `(inclusive-range 0 1 -1)`.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you want to write some function like this:

```
(defn my-range [start & {:keys [up-to down-to]}]
  (cond (and (nil? up-to) (nil? down-to)) (range (inc start))
        (nil? down-to) (range start (inc up-to))
        :else (range start (dec down-to) -1)))

user> (my-range 10)
(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)

user> (my-range 0 :up-to 10)
(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)

user> (my-range 10 :down-to -10)
(10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7 -8 -9 -10)
```

It is slightly more verbose, but it conforms to a simlpe range behaviour, and adds some sugary syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You can define something equivalent to range but inclusive like so:

```
(defn irange
  ([start end step]
   (take-while (if (pos? step) #(<= % end) #(>= % end)) (iterate #(+ % step) start)))
  ([start end]
   (irange start end 1))
  ([end]
   (irange 0 end))
  ([] (range)))
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer imo.  (See my comment on @Thumbnail's answer.)

Answer (score 0):

There's no standard inclusive range function in Clojure, but you can do it by

```
(defn inclusive-range [n] (map inc (range 0 n)))
(inclusive-range 10)
```

range 0 will also get incremented so keep it -1

One more solution to the same

```
(defn inclusive-range [count] (range 0 (+ 1 count) ))
```